# Matlab: Color Coding a 3D Plot

Tags: matlab, colors, 3d

I've been trying to look around online for something I want but I'm not having much luck so I thought I would just ask on here.

Is it possible to pinpoint in a different color and show the point on the graph where there are intersections between the two plots?

Thanks for any help you can give.

Here is the code:

```
file1 = fopen('C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\avatar1.txt'); % open text file
file2 = fopen('C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\avatar2.txt'); % open text file
file3 = fopen('C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\avatar3.txt'); % open text file

tline1 = fgetl(file1); % read line by line and remove new line characters
tline2 = fgetl(file2); % read line by line and remove new line characters
tline3 = fgetl(file3); % read line by line and remove new line characters

% declare empty arrays
CX1 = [];
CY1 = [];
CZ1 = [];

CX2 = [];
CY2 = [];
CZ2 = [];

CX3 = [];
CY3 = [];
CZ3 = [];


while ischar(tline1) % true if tline is a character array
    temp = cell2mat(textscan(tline1, '<%n,%n,%n>'));

    % convert all the cell fields to a matrix
    CX1 = vertcat(CX1, temp(1));
    CY1 = vertcat(CY1, temp(2));
    CZ1 = vertcat(CZ1, temp(3));

    tline1 = fgetl(file1);
end

while ischar(tline2) % true if tline is a character array
    temp = cell2mat(textscan(tline2, '<%n,%n,%n>'));

    % convert all the cell fields to a matrix
    CX2 = vertcat(CX2, temp(1));
    CY2 = vertcat(CY2, temp(2));
    CZ2 = vertcat(CZ2, temp(3));

    tline2 = fgetl(file2);
end

while ischar(tline3) % true if tline is a character array
    temp = cell2mat(textscan(tline3, '<%n,%n,%n>'));

    % convert all the cell fields to a matrix
    CX3 = vertcat(CX3, temp(1));
    CY3 = vertcat(CY3, temp(2));
    CZ3 = vertcat(CZ3, temp(3));

    tline3 = fgetl(file3);
end

fclose(file1); % close the file
fclose(file2); % close the file
fclose(file3); % close the file

plot3(CX1, CY1, CZ1) % plot the data and label the axises
plot3(CX2, CY2, CZ2)
plot3(CX3, CY3, CZ3)
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
zlabel('z') 
grid on
axis square
rotate3d on; % activate interactive mouse rotation
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your question - do you want to draw one graph in one colour and overlay the other in a different colour, then highlight the intersecting points?

Comment: Yes, but it's 3 graphs. So 3 different colors then highlight or pinpoint the intersections.

Comment: Are you asking how to put markers in the intersections... or how to determine if there are intersections, and if so, where they are?

Comment: How to determine and mark them.

Comment: Please see my answer thus far and clarify your meaning of intersection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the colours is simple, that's just a case of adding a colour code to the plot3 command, e.g.:

```
plot3(CX1, CY1, CZ1, 'b'); % blue lines/markers
plot3(CX2, CY2, CZ2, 'r'); % red lines/markers
plot3(CX3, CY3, CZ3, 'g'); % green lines/markers
```

For more details on colour codes, see the [Matlab Colourspec Page](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/colorspec.html).

The intersection could be a bit more tricky, depending on whether you want the intersection of the points (i.e. specific points which appear in all 3 datasets) or the intersection points of the lines that join the points.

I think the former should be fairly easy (this is untested and assumes `CX1`,etc are vertical vectors):

```
figure; % Open up a new figure
hold on; % This means the everything you plot stays in the figure and is not overwritten

% Plot the original points
plot3(CX1, CY1, CZ1, '-*b'); % blue lines/markers
plot3(CX2, CY2, CZ2, '-*r'); % red lines/markers
plot3(CX3, CY3, CZ3, '-*g'); % green lines/markers

% turn those 1xn vectors into 3xn matrices for each set of points
points1 = [CX1, CY1, CZ1];
points2 = [CX2, CY2, CZ2];
points3 = [CX3, CY3, CZ3];

% Find the intersection of the 3 sets
CX_intersect = intersect( points1, intersect( points2, points3, 'rows'), 'rows');

% Draw a scatter plot of the intersection points. the 'mo' means:
% m: magenta in colour, o: circular markers
scatter3( CX_intersect(:,1),CX_intersect(:,2),CX_intersect(:,3),'mo');
```

The intersection works like so:

Say we have 3 matrices, each containing a number of 3d points. Let's call them `A`,`B` and `C`.

To find the intersection between all 3 sets we first find the points that intersect just in `A` and `B`. We now have a set of points that we know are in `A` and `B`, so now we just have to check if those points are in `C` as well. we do this by doing another intersection.

I just chained those together into one line of code, which was probably not very useful, so I apologise. The code for the `A`,`B`,`C` intersections is below:

```
D = intersect(A,B,'rows') % we use rows because each row represents a 3D point
E = intersect(C,D,'rows') % E is the intersection of the 3 sets.
```

We can then substitute D into the line `E = ...` and we get:

```
E = intersect( intersect(A,B,'rows'), C, 'rows' );
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That's how I thought you change the colors but your code just turned them all lime green... As for the intersection I want to find any intersection between the 3 matrices and if there is an intersection pinpoint it with a different color and show the vector value of the intersection

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on now but your intersections work but made the graph completely disappear?? Also, do you know why they only changed to 1 lime green color?

Comment: I've edited my example to a more full one. I think, because you weren't using `hold on`, only the last `plot3` call was showing (by default Matlab gets rid of the old plot before drawing the new one). That would explain why they were all green.

The intersection will be easier to explain in the question, so I'll edit it now.